# How to implement origin/anchor point in GLKit scene graph?

Tags: matrix, glkit, scenegraph

I'm trying to implement a simple scene graph on iOS using GLKit but handling origin/anchor points is giving me fits. The requirements are pretty straightforward:

- There is a graph of nodes each with translation, rotation, scale and
  origin point.
- Each node combines the properties above into a single
  matrix (which is multiplied by it's parent's matrix if it has a
  parent).
- Nodes need to honor their parent's coordinate system,
  including the origin point (i.e. barring translations, etc. a child's origin should line up with the parent's origin)

So the question is:

What operations (e.g. translationMatrix * rotationMatrix * scaleMatrix, etc.) need to be performed and in what order so as to achieve the proper handling of origin/anchor points?

P.S. - If you are kind enough to post an answer please mention whether your answer is based on column or row major matrices - that's a perennial source of confusion for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at both **SpriteKit** and **SceneKit**. Both APIs provide the building blocks for creating scene graphs on iOS.

Comment: Please give more details on how to use these APIs to solve the question.